# How to add shift key in Android custom keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, android-keypad

I am working on custom keyboard. I want to add shift key and to change xml file when user press it.

**lowercase.xml**

```
<!--
 Copyright (C) 2008-2012  OMRON SOFTWARE Co., Ltd.

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:keyWidth="10%p"
      android:horizontalGap="0dip"
      android:verticalGap="0dip"
      android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"
      >

  <Row>
    <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
    <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
    <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
    <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
    <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
    <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"/>
    <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="i"/>
    <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o"/>
    <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
  </Row>

  <Row>
    <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="a" android:horizontalGap="5%p"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="115" android:keyLabel="s"/>
    <Key android:codes="100" android:keyLabel="d"/>
    <Key android:codes="102" android:keyLabel="f"/>
    <Key android:codes="103" android:keyLabel="g"/>
    <Key android:codes="104" android:keyLabel="h"/>
    <Key android:codes="106" android:keyLabel="j"/>
    <Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="k"/>
    <Key android:codes="108" android:keyLabel="l" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
  </Row>

  <Row>
    <Key android:codes="00"
     android:keyIcon="@drawable/key_qwerty_shift" android:iconPreview="@drawable/key_qwerty_shift_b" android:keyWidth="15%p" android:isModifier="true" android:isSticky="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="122" android:keyLabel="z"/>
    <Key android:codes="120" android:keyLabel="x"/>
    <Key android:codes="99" android:keyLabel="c"/>
    <Key android:codes="118" android:keyLabel="v"/>
    <Key android:codes="98" android:keyLabel="b"/>
    <Key android:codes="110" android:keyLabel="n"/>
    <Key android:codes="109" android:keyLabel="m"/>
    <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyIcon="@drawable/key_del" android:iconPreview="@drawable/key_del_b" android:keyWidth="15%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
  </Row>

  <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
    <Key android:codes="00" android:keyLabel="123" android:keyWidth="15%p"  android:popupKeyboard="@xml/default_en_symbols" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="44" android:keyLabel="," android:keyWidth="10%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="32" android:keyIcon="@drawable/key_qwerty_space" android:iconPreview="@drawable/key_qwerty_space_b" android:keyWidth="40%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
    <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="."  android:keyWidth="10%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="63" android:keyLabel="\?" android:keyWidth="10%p"/>
    <Key android:codes="13" android:keyIcon="@drawable/key_enter" android:iconPreview="@drawable/key_enter_b" android:keyWidth="15%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
  </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

and upercase.xml

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="6%p"
    >


    <Row   android:keyWidth="18%p">
        <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
        <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
        <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4"/>
        <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
        <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6"/>
        <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7"/>
        <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
        <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
        <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>

    </Row>
    <Row   >
        <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="Q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="W"/>
        <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="E"/>
        <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="R"/>
        <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="T"/>
        <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="Y"/>
        <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="U"/>
        <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="I"/>
        <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="O"/>
        <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="P" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>

    <Row    >
        <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="." android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="A"/>
        <Key android:codes="115" android:keyLabel="S"/>
        <Key android:codes="100" android:keyLabel="D"/>
        <Key android:codes="102" android:keyLabel="F"/>
        <Key android:codes="103" android:keyLabel="G"/>
        <Key android:codes="104" android:keyLabel="H"/>
        <Key android:codes="106" android:keyLabel="J"/>
        <Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="K"/>
        <Key android:codes="108" android:keyLabel="L" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
        <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete"
            android:keyWidth="15%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:isRepeatable="true"/>
    </Row>

    <Row    android:keyHeight="8%p">
        <Key android:codes="00"
     android:keyIcon="@drawable/key_qwerty_shift"       android:iconPreview="@drawable/key_qwerty_shift_b" android:keyWidth="15%p" android:isModifier="true" android:isSticky="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="SPACE"
            android:keyWidth="20%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:codes="122" android:keyLabel="Z"/>
        <Key android:codes="120" android:keyLabel="X"/>
        <Key android:codes="99" android:keyLabel="C"/>
        <Key android:codes="118" android:keyLabel="V"/>
        <Key android:codes="98" android:keyLabel="B"/>
        <Key android:codes="110" android:keyLabel="N"/>
        <Key android:codes="109" android:keyLabel="M"/>
        <Key android:codes="10" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_return"
            android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>

    </Row>


</Keyboard>
```

CustomKeyboard.java

```
class CustomKeyboard {

    /** A link to the KeyboardView that is used to render this CustomKeyboard. */
    private KeyboardView mKeyboardView;
    /** A link to the activity that hosts the {@link #mKeyboardView}. */
    private Activity mHostActivity;

    /** The key (code) handler. */
    private OnKeyboardActionListener mOnKeyboardActionListener = new OnKeyboardActionListener() {

        public final static int CodeDelete = -5; // Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE
        public final static int CodePrev = 55000;
        public final static int CodeNext = 55001;
        public final static int CodeDone = 55002;

        @Override
        public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
            // NOTE We can say '<Key android:codes="49,50" ... >' in the xml
            // file; all codes come in keyCodes, the first in this list in
            // primaryCode
            // Get the EditText and its Editable
            View focusCurrent = mHostActivity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
            if (focusCurrent == null
                    || focusCurrent.getClass() != EditText.class)
                return;
            EditText edittext = (EditText) focusCurrent;
            Editable editable = edittext.getText();
            int start = edittext.getSelectionStart();
            // Apply the key to the edittext
            if (primaryCode == CodeDone) {
                hideCustomKeyboard();
            } 
            else if (primaryCode == CodeDelete) 
            {
                if (editable != null && start > 0)
                    editable.delete(start - 1, start);
            } 
            else if (primaryCode == CodePrev) {
                View focusNew = edittext.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_BACKWARD);
                if (focusNew != null)
                    focusNew.requestFocus();
            } 
            else if (primaryCode == CodeNext) {
                View focusNew = edittext.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_FORWARD);
                if (focusNew != null)
                    focusNew.requestFocus();
            } 
            else { // insert character
                editable.insert(start, Character.toString((char) primaryCode));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPress(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onText(CharSequence text) {
        }

        @Override
        public void swipeDown() {
        }

        @Override
        public void swipeLeft() {
        }

        @Override
        public void swipeRight() {
        }

        @Override
        public void swipeUp() {
        }
    };

    /**
     * Create a custom keyboard, that uses the KeyboardView (with resource id
     * <var>viewid</var>) of the <var>host</var> activity, and load the keyboard
     * layout from xml file <var>layoutid</var> (see {@link Keyboard} for
     * description). Note that the <var>host</var> activity must have a
     * <var>KeyboardView</var> in its layout (typically aligned with the bottom
     * of the activity). Note that the keyboard layout xml file may include key
     * codes for navigation; see the constants in this class for their values.
     * Note that to enable EditText's to use this custom keyboard, call the
     * {@link #registerEditText(int)}.
     * 
     * @param host
     *            The hosting activity.
     * @param viewid
     *            The id of the KeyboardView.
     * @param layoutid
     *            The id of the xml file containing the keyboard layout.
     */
    public CustomKeyboard(Activity host, int viewid, int layoutid) {
        mHostActivity = host;
        mKeyboardView = (KeyboardView) mHostActivity.findViewById(viewid);
        mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutid));
        mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false); // NOTE Do not show the preview
                                                // balloons
        mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(mOnKeyboardActionListener);
        // Hide the standard keyboard initially
        mHostActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

    /** Returns whether the CustomKeyboard is visible. */
    public boolean isCustomKeyboardVisible() {
        return mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }

    /**
     * Make the CustomKeyboard visible, and hide the system keyboard for view v.
     */
    public void showCustomKeyboard(View v) {
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mKeyboardView.setEnabled(true);
        if (v != null)
            ((InputMethodManager) mHostActivity
                    .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                    .hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    /** Make the CustomKeyboard invisible. */
    public void hideCustomKeyboard() {
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mKeyboardView.setEnabled(false);
    }

    /**
     * Register <var>EditText<var> with resource id <var>resid</var> (on the
     * hosting activity) for using this custom keyboard.
     * 
     * @param resid
     *            The resource id of the EditText that registers to the custom
     *            keyboard.
     */
    public void registerEditText(int resid) {
        // Find the EditText 'resid'
        EditText edittext = (EditText) mHostActivity.findViewById(resid);
        // Make the custom keyboard appear
        edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            // NOTE By setting the on focus listener, we can show the custom
            // keyboard when the edit box gets focus, but also hide it when the
            // edit box loses focus
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus)
                    showCustomKeyboard(v);
                else
                    hideCustomKeyboard();
            }
        });
        edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // NOTE By setting the on click listener, we can show the custom
            // keyboard again, by tapping on an edit box that already had focus
            // (but that had the keyboard hidden).
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCustomKeyboard(v);
            }
        });
        // Disable standard keyboard hard way
        // NOTE There is also an easy way:
        // 'edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)' (but you will not have a
        // cursor, and no 'edittext.setCursorVisible(true)' doesn't work )
        edittext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                EditText edittext = (EditText) v;
                int inType = edittext.getInputType(); // Backup the input type
                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // Disable standard
                                                            // keyboard
                edittext.onTouchEvent(event); // Call native handler
                edittext.setInputType(inType); // Restore input type
                return true; // Consume touch event
            }
        });
        // Disable spell check (hex strings look like words to Android)
        edittext.setInputType(edittext.getInputType()
                | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    }

}
```

Please help me convert from uppercase keyboard to lowercase keyboard.

Comment: got solution from soft keypad example for android

Comment: Can u share a small snippet or ref to the code .. im also in the hunt of same

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question. Just came across it. Here's my take on an answer for future reference if someone is interested.
Add:

```
<Key android:codes="-1" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_shift" android:keyWidth="12.5%p"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
```

to add the shift key on your left side for instance.
Then add this to your onKey() method as another IF:

```
 else if (primaryCode == -1){
     caps = !caps;
     keyboard.setShifted(caps);
     mKeyboardView.invalidateAllKeys()
 }
```

where keyboard is an instance of your Keyboard that is inflated using one of the xmls. For instance:

```
keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.lowercase);
```

caps is a flag that determines whether to shift to UPPER case or SHIFT back to LOWER case. This should basically shift your keyboard when the key is clicked.

p.s
You should use a switch case statement instead of all those if else statements.